# iOS: How do I sort my table view using a integer value but wanting to display a string value?

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have the following to lines to sort and section out my tableview.

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptorState = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"positionSort" ascending:YES];
```

The above is a integer value that sorts out my cells by their respective positionSort value.
I also have the below code to display section names; however, the sections still appear in alphabetical order instead of in order of positionSort. How can I correct this?

```
NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"position" cacheName:@"Master"];
```

Thanks!

UPDATE: Thanks to @MartinR I was able to arrive at an answer.

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];

    // Here I build up one of my Position objects using my unique position passed.
    // I had to cast the object as NSMutableString* to get rid of a warning
    Position * aPosition = [Position positionWithUniquePosition:(NSMutableString *)[[[sectionInfo objects] objectAtIndex: 0] position]
                                         inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

    // Once the above is done then I simply just accessed the attribute from my object
    return aPosition.positionDescription;

}
```

Comment: I don't think you have posted enough to go on here. I do something very much like this and it has never caused me any problem.

Comment: Is `positionSort` really an Integer attribute or is it a String attribute that contains the integer as string? - And keep in mind that if you use different keys for the sort descriptor and for the `sectionNameKeyPath` then both keys must generate the same relative ordering.

Comment: @MartinR yes they are different. positionSort (ie: 1,21,22,40, etc.) and position (ie. Manager, Clerk, etc.)  So basically I'm trying to get the titles (positions) to show up in an order other than alphabetically. That's why I had the posSort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `initWithFetchRequest:managedObjectContext:sectionNameKeyPath:cacheName:` documentation:

> sectionNameKeyPath
>
> ... If this
>   key path is not the same as that specified by the first sort
>   descriptor in fetchRequest, they must generate the same relative
>   orderings. For example, the first sort descriptor in fetchRequest
>   might specify the key for a persistent property; sectionNameKeyPath
>   might specify a key for a transient property derived from the
>   persistent property.

So you cannot use "positionSort" in the sort descriptor and "position" in the `sectionNameKeyPath`, because sorting numbers and sorting strings does not generate the same relative orderings.

I would use "positionSort" for both and change `tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:` so that it returns the position name as section title instead of the position number.

I did not try this myself but something like this should work:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section { 
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.controller sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [[[sectionInfo objects] objectAtIndex:0] position];
}
```

Comment: Thanks this was a great help. I'll include what this answer led me to in my question as an update -- perhaps it will be of some use to someone else.